# Misunderstanding how $H^{\oplus A} \cong H^A$ for finite sets $A$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

*This is on page 77 of Chapter 0 by Paolo Aluffi.*

So consider how if we have some set $A $ and an abelian group $H $ then $H^A = \text{Hom}_{\textsf {Set}}(A,H)$ has a natural abelian group structure. Well Aluffi says we can define a subset $H^{\oplus A}$ of $H^A$ as:

> $$H^{\oplus A} := \{ \alpha : A \to H \ | \ \alpha (a) \neq e_H \quad \text {for only finitely many elements } a \in A \}.$$

Please correct me if wrong, but I've been thinking he means by this that no element $a \in A $ will ever be mapped to $e_H \in H$ by a function $\alpha \in H^{\oplus A}$, unless there will be infinitely other elements $a$ also mapping to $e_H$.

The problem I arrive to is due to his next assertion:

> The reader should note that $H^{\oplus A}$ is the whole of $H^A$ if
>   $A$ is a finite set.

How could it be the whole of $H^A$ if it doesnt allow mappings from any elements of $A $ to $e_H$?

Comment: If is a condition on $\alpha$. Not a condition on $a$. If $A$ is a finite set then automatically **every** $\alpha:A\to H$ satisfies this condition so is an element the set $H^{\oplus A}$. So then $H^A=H^{\oplus A}$.

Comment: $\alpha \in H^{\oplus A}$ means that there are only finitely many elements $a \in A$ in the domain that get mapped to non-identity things. Sometimes people say "almost all" $a \in A$ get mapped to the identity. Think of the difference between a power series that can have infinitely many terms, like $1/(1-x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$, versus a polynomial, where only finitely many terms can have nonzero coefficients—for all but finitely many terms, the coefficient has to be zero (the additive identity).

Comment: In different language, this is just talking about the difference between the direct sum and the direct product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the definition of $H^{\oplus A}$.  It is the set of all $\alpha:A\to H$ such that $\{a\in A:\alpha(a)\neq e_H\}$ is a finite set.  If $A$ is finite, then $\{a\in A:\alpha(a)\neq e_H\}$ is always finite since it is a subset of $A$, so every $\alpha:A\to H$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: Ahhh, I see it now! Sorry for the late response and thank you.